# Express 4.17 get raw body for one endpoint

Tags: javascript, express, parsing, stripe-payments

I am trying to implement Stripe in my web API and need to read the raw body of the request. I already have existing API paths in my application that does NOT need the raw body.

The code I have implemented is based Stripe documentation example, see below.

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('apikey...');
const endpointSecret = 'whsec_...';

const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.post('/webhook', express.raw({type: 'application/json'}), (request, response) => {
  let event = request.body;
  console.log('body', event);
  const headers = JSON.stringify(request.headers);
  console.log('Headers', headers);
  // Only verify the event if you have an endpoint secret defined.
  // Otherwise use the basic event deserialized with JSON.parse
  if (endpointSecret) {
    // Get the signature sent by Stripe
    const signature = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.body, signature, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
      return response.sendStatus(400);
    }
  }

  // Handle the event
  ...
  // Return a 200 response to acknowledge receipt of the event
  response.send();
});

app.listen(443, () => console.log('Running on port 443'));
```

This code logs the below messages - since the raw body is empty.

```
body
Headers {"host":".....}
⚠️ Webhook signature verification failed. No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing
```

I have tried to fix this by adding a middleware to read the raw body.

```
// Custom middleware that keeps the raw request body. This is needed for Stripe
app.use((req, res, next)=>{
  req.rawBody = '';
  req.on('data', (chunk) => { req.rawBody += chunk; });
  req.on('end', () => {
    try {
      req.body = JSON.parse(req.rawBody);
      next();
    } catch (err) {
      console.log('Error parsing body')
      next();
    }
   });
 });

app.post('/webhook', (request, response) => {
  let event = request.body;
  console.log('rawBody', request.rawBody)
  if (endpointSecret) {
    // Get the signature sent by Stripe
    const signature = request.headers['stripe-signature'];
    try {
      event = stripe.webhooks.constructEvent(request.rawBody, signature, endpointSecret);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`⚠️  Webhook signature verification failed.`, err.message);
      return resp.sendStatus(400);
    }
```

According to logging the raw body is still empty. I still get the same error message in console.

How can I add the raw body to the request? Preferably using a middleware.
Kind regards /K

UPDATE: (Thanks Bravo!)
The below code seems to work by exposing the raw body

```
app.post('/webhook', express.raw(), (request, response) => {
      let event = request.rawBody;
```

Comment: have you tried just `express.raw()` - it could be that you're sending an empty body too, of course

Comment: Hi Bravo! Thanks for the reply! Yes, the first example uses `express.raw()`. I am sending requests from the Stripe developer webhooks dashboard, so the body should not be empty.

Comment: no, the first example uses `express.raw({type: 'application/json'})` - clearly not just `express.raw()`

Comment: Please can you update your webhook handler to use the [`bodyParser`](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser) middleware as per the [official documentation](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures#verify-official-libraries).

Comment: Ah, yes. My bad. :) I tried now with express.raw() and it seems to be working by accessing req.rawBody. :D I wish to avoid body-parser since it is deprecated in Express 4. Many thanks! /K

Comment: express.raw() doesn't exist anymore right? (express 4.16.4)

Comment: The express.raw() middleware is available in Express v4.17.0 onwards. :) 
https://devdocs.io/express/index#express.raw

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by adding the `verify` method to the `express.json` middleware config (which uses `body-parser` under the hood).

Example:

```js
const RAW_BODY_WHITELIST = ['/webhooks/stripe'];

app.use(express.json({
  verify: (req: Request, _res: Response, buf: Buffer, _encoding: string) => {
    if (RAW_BODY_WHITELIST.includes(req.path)) {
      req.rawBody = buf.toString();
    }
  },
}));
```

This way, you can keep all your middleware nicely organised and don't have to declare webhook routes before or between other middleware.

Comment: For me somehow `express.json` was not working. From [here](https://flaviocopes.com/express-get-raw-body/), I changed to `bodyParser.json` and your code was working fine.